# Subnet's router access from primary network

Tags: networking

i've seen a lot of theese posts, but no one has helped me.
I have a primary network in my house, with the ISP given router. (full access to it) Gateway: 192.168.1.1 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

Today i used an old TP-Link N600 (that i will call router B) to create a wifi subnet for a part of my house that was not covered by the wifi network.
So i created a subnet, with the router B as gateway at 192.168.0.1, connected at the primary network via static ip at 192.168.1.2

Everything is working fine, as my wifi is giving internet access to phones and tablets.
I can also access at primary router's page while being connected at secondary network.

The only thing i can't to is connect to the configuration page of router B while connected to router A (either LAN or wifi).

How can i solve this?

Comment: Why not connect router B so that it is on the same subnet as your main network?  That is what I do and lots of people do , so as to have one subnet.   Connect a LAN  port on Router B to Router A; give Router B a static IP on your network; turn DHCP OFF on Router B.

Comment: I tried this but without success. I just connected Router B (WAN Port) to router A. But how can i configure router B to be a part of router A subnet?

Comment: Use a LAN port on Router B, not a WAN port (different, disconnected subnets). Log into Router B directly (connect a computer to it) and go to the LAN section , give that an address on the main network, go do DHCP and disable that, connect an Ethernet cable from a LAN port on B to a LAN port on A, then restart B (unplug it, wait 15 seconds, start it back up again)

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly! Is there any way i can use the same network SSD or i should put a different one?

Comment: Try either way and check. I will post my answer since it worked and hopefully you will acknowledge it. It depends in part on your wifi cards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to set up.

Use a LAN port on Router B, not a WAN port (different, disconnected subnets).

Log into Router B directly (connect a computer to it) and go to the LAN section , give that an address on the main network, go do DHCP and disable that, connect an Ethernet cable from a LAN port on B to a LAN port on A, then restart B (unplug it, wait 15 seconds, start it back up again)

Comment: Just to let you know. I used two different networks setup at the end, but it's working for a little while and then it stops sharing internet connection, i really don't know why.

Comment: Just try using one subnet to eliminate your difficulties. That always works for me.